# Foundation 5 no longer using xlarge and xxlarge grid sizes

Tags: css, sass, media-queries, zurb-foundation

## Problem

In Foundation 5.0.2 and up, it is not using the xlarge and xxlarge grid sizes. They worked in prior versions 5.0.0 and 5.0.1.

So when going into the css file from foundation, it will only show small, medium, and large grid sizes.

Apparently no version of Foundation 5 has xlarge and xxlarge block-grids either.

## Question

Is there a way to get these to work again?

## Tests

I went to their website and downloaded the latest 5.1.1, and it had the same issue in foundation.css.

I'm building it myself with Sass and also tried adding in the override variables in there manually:

```
// Here we define the lower and upper bounds for each media size
$small-range: 0em, 40em // 0, 640px
$medium-range: 40.063em, 64em // 641px, 1024px
$large-range: 64.063em, 90em // 1025px, 1440px
$xlarge-range: 90.063em, 120em // 1441px, 1920px
$xxlarge-range: 120.063em // 1921px

$screen: "only screen"

$landscape: "#{$screen} and (orientation: landscape)"
$portrait: "#{$screen} and (orientation: portrait)"

$small-up: $screen
$small-only: "#{$screen} and (max-width: #{upper-bound($small-range)})"

$medium-up: "#{$screen} and (min-width:#{lower-bound($medium-range)})"
$medium-only: "#{$screen} and (min-width:#{lower-bound($medium-range)}) and (max-width:#{upper-bound($medium-range)})"

$large-up: "#{$screen} and (min-width:#{lower-bound($large-range)})"
$large-only: "#{$screen} and (min-width:#{lower-bound($large-range)}) and (max-width:#{upper-bound($large-range)})"

$xlarge-up: "#{$screen} and (min-width:#{lower-bound($xlarge-range)})"
$xlarge-only: "#{$screen} and (min-width:#{lower-bound($xlarge-range)}) and (max-width:#{upper-bound($xlarge-range)})"

$xxlarge-up: "#{$screen} and (min-width:#{lower-bound($xxlarge-range)})"
$xxlarge-only: "#{$screen} and (min-width:#{lower-bound($xxlarge-range)}) and (max-width:#{upper-bound($xxlarge-range)})"
```

Comment: I just ran a compile (Foundation 5.1) and it seemed to work for me. I was able to successfully do `@media #{$xxlarge-up}`. Try double-checking to make sure you're loading functions, settings, then components in that order

Comment: @jonsuh The media queries aren't the issue, it's the grid sizes which are not present in the compiled CSS file. You might've replied before I edited that sorry.

Comment: Gotcha—sorry, I misunderstood your question. I posted the solution. They have it disabled by default.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In your `settings` file uncomment and set the following as true (It's line 32 for me):

```
$include-xl-html-grid-classes: true;
```

Then recompile and the xlarge and xxlarge classes should be present. (Make sure to get rid of your overrides, just in case there's a conflict)

Comment: This does not enable xlarge-block-grid and xxlarge-block-grid, am I right?

Comment: @coorasse Correct. For the xlarge and xxlarge block grids, you have uncomment and set the following as true in your settings file: `$include-xl-html-block-grid-classes: true;`

Comment: Where do I find this "settings.scss" in the Foundation ?

Answer (score 5):

This has been changed in Foundation 6. In `_settings.scss` you now find the `$breakpoint-classes` list and add the extra classes you want. e.g.

```
$breakpoint-classes: (small medium large xlarge);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use both of this to enable the xlarge and xxlarge class

```
 $breakpoints: {
  small: 0,
  medium: 640px,
  large: 1024px,
  xlarge: 1200px,
  xxlarge: 1440px,
}
$include-xl-html-grid-classes: true;
$breakpoint-classes: (small medium large xlarge xxlarge);
```